# Can I force apple mail to display "Re:" again instead of the German (and bad) translation of "Aw:"

Tags: mail.app, email, settings

Since I upgraded to Mavericks, Apple Mail will display localized versions of subject prefixes, even if the original received mail used the English prefixes. I find that quite annoying, as this does not conform to standards and conflicts with other mail clients.

So in my German Mail.app, I get

```
"Aw:" instead of "Re:"
"Wtr: instead of "Fwd:"
```

Is there a possibility to get back the old behavior which uses the English prefixes?

Comment: Are you talking about mails you are receiving or mail you are sending?

Comment: I'm talking about received mails. Even if other mail clients show these as "Subject: Re: balabal", apple mail displays "Subject: Aw:"

Comment: Maybe other clients rewrite the subject line and OS X Mail.app doesn't. Can you have a look at the raw mail (Opt-Cmd-U) to see whether you receive them with Re or with Aw?

Comment: @patrix: No, its definitely Mail.app. Mail headers show "Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Fwd: ...", but the display is "Wtr: ...". I also checked that with other mail clients connected to the same account. They still show the real subject

Comment: Interesting, doesn't happen here (with Swiss/German settings).

Comment: Upps, I have to retract that :-) Same thing happens here as well, I just never noticed. Oh well.